# How would do this Algebra question?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

$(b)$ Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $X$ an indeterminate, and consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}[X].$ 
 $\quad(\mathsf{i})$ Let $f(X),g(X)\in\mathbb{F}[X]$ with $f(X),g(X)\neq0.$ Prove that $f(X)g(X)\neq0.$ 
 $\quad(\mathsf{ii})$ Is $\mathbb{F}[X]$ an integral domain? Justify your answer. *You may assume that $\mathbb{F}[X]$ is a commutative ring.*

How would I answer each part of this question, it makes no sense?

Comment: Hint: (i) answers (ii).

Comment: It does make sense. Here's a reformulation of (i): Show that the product of two non-zero polynomials is non-zero, as long as the coefficients are from a field.

Answer (score 3):

i) Consider the leading coefficient of $f(x)g(x)$

ii) Yes, by the point i)

Comment: why for part two?

Comment: Because it's the definition of integral domain: if $f\neq 0 $ and $g \neq 0$ then $fg \neq 0$

Comment: yeah i get it thanks